# Can't restart after shutdown?

Tags: boot

I shut power off before my Ubuntu 12.04 had completely loaded  and on power up I now get the following messages.

```
udevd[146]: inotify_add_watch(6, /dev/dm-1) failed: no such file or directory

mount: mounting /dev on /root.sys failed: No such file or directory
mount: mounting /sys on /root/sys failed: no such file or directory
mount: mounting /proc on /root/proc failed: No such file or directory
Target filesystem doesn't have requested /sbin/init.
No init found. Try passing init= bootarg.
```

then BusyBox comes up with following prompt

```
(initramis)
```

Though I have a programming background I have been an enduser for a couple of decades now.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Maybe GEUB doesn't know where the root partition is. I think holding down shilf while loading brings you to the GRUB menu (not sure about the key). Then you can try to manually load: http://askubuntu.com/questions/169742/grub-shell-greets-me-at-boot-up-instead-of-a-menu

Answer (score 1):

these happens due to problem with grub bootloader

First boot your system with typing following commands

```
root (hd0,1)
linux /vmlinuz-blqh-blqh root=/dev/sda3
initrd /init-blqh-blq root=/dev/sda3
boot
```

Here sda3 may be change with your system partition. if you fail try sda1,sda2 or so.

After booting your system. you can repair your boot loader with boot-repair tool. you will get more info about boot-repair tool via following link.

click on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair